# Wrapping three specific routes with the same component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have three routes, /login, /signup and /forgot and their corresponding components which only contain the basic forms you'd expect. I would like those components to be contained within a landing page component without having to put my landing page logic within my three components because that would reload the container and my transitions wouldn't show.

My landing page has something like this going on

```
<h1>Welcome to my web app</h1>
<transition name="slide" mode="">
   <router-view></router-view>
<transition>
```

routes.js looks like this

```
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Forgot from './components/Forgot';
export const routes = [
    { path: '/signup', component: SignUp },
    { path: '/login', component: SignIn },
    { path: '', component: SignIn },
    { path: '/forgot', component: Forgot }
];
```

Would I need some intermediary hidden route or something? Or would I only wrap the container based on conditional logic in App.vue (which, to me, doesn't seem like good practice)?

Answer (score 4):

In router.js you can send the currentComponent as a props,

```
import landingPage from './components/LandingPage';
export const routes = [
    { path: '/signup', component: landingPage, props: { currentComponent: 'SignUp' } },
    { path: '/login', component: landingPage, props: { currentComponent: 'SignIn' } },
    { path: '', component: landingPage, props: { currentComponent: 'SignIn' } },
    { path: '/forgot', component: landingPage, props: { currentComponent: 'Forgot' } }
];
```

and consider the landing page as a component (LandingPage.vue)

```
<template>    
<h1>Welcome to my web app</h1>
    <transition name="slide" mode="">
       <component :is="currentComponent">
    <transition>
</template>

<script>
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Forgot from './components/Forgot';
export default {
  components: ['SignUp', 'SignIn', 'Forgot'],
  props: ['currentComponent']
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's "props", not "prop" in the route options: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work using named nested `<router-view>` elements like this

routes.js

```
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Forgot from './components/Forgot';
import RegistrationWrapper from './components/RegistrationWrapper';

export const routes = [{
    path: '/signup',
    components: {
        default: SignUp,
        'wrapper': RegistrationWrapper
    }
}, {
    path: '/login',
    components: {
        default: SignIn,
        'wrapper': RegistrationWrapper
    }
}, {
    path: '/forgot',
    components: {
        default: Forgot,
        'wrapper': RegistrationWrapper
    }
}, {
    path: '/',
    components: {
        default: SignIn,
        'wrapper': RegistrationWrapper
    }
}];
```

RegistrationWrapper.vue

```
<template>
   <h1>Welcome to my web app</h1>
   <transition name="slide" mode="">
      <slot></slot>
   <transition>
<template>
```

and my App.vue looks like this

```
<template>
    <div>
       <router-view name="wrapper">
          <router-view></router-view>
       </router-view>
   </div>
</template>
```

The only downside to this that I can see is the fact that I now have to supply a wrapper to all my routes which will probably get redundant. How would I detect if wrapper was supplied or not in App.vue? Also, is there another downside I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

[Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html) should take care of your problem nicely. Here is an example from the docs:

Here in following component, `User` part is same in both the routes, internal content needs to be different in these routes:

```
/user/foo/profile                     /user/foo/posts
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
| User             |                  | User            |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
| | Profile      | |  +------------>  | | Posts       | |
| |              | |                  | |             | |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
```

`<router-view>` is a top-level outlet. It renders the component matched by a top level route. Similarly, a rendered component can also contain its own, nested `<router-view>`. For example, if we add one inside the User component's template:

```
const User = {
  template: `
    <div class="user">
      <h2>User {{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `
}
```

To render components into this nested outlet, we need to use the children option in VueRouter constructor config:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

Comment: I was thinking so but the main problem for me is how do I hide the route from the url? I think having something like mysite.com/landing/login is a little unintuitive.

Comment: @MathieuBertin Find some better words :P `mysite.com/registration/login`. However there might be better solution available.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to do this while keeping the url as mysite.com/login.

Comment: Plus, registration doesn't seem like it makes sense for logging in.

Comment: I found a solution for this that works for me. Not sure if it's the best way to go about it but I'd appreciate some feedback. Let me know if you can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

For [vue-router 4](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#route)  it's more easy in this way:

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <Wrapper>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </Wrapper>
</router-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer has been in the docs all along:

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

Although a bit hard to wrap your head around, it means you can write something like this:

```
 {
    path: '/login',
    component: () => import ('@/pages/SignInSignUpWrapper.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import ('@/pages/SignIn.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/signup',
        component: () => import ('@/pages/SignUp.vue')
      }
    ]
  },
```

This will produce only two routes: `/login` and `/signup`.
They'll both have `SignInSignUpWrapper` component as parent, and the components will render in `SignInSignUpWrapper`'s `<route-view>`'s slot